# Same button on multiple activities

Tags: android, android-activity, global

right i have a sign in button located exactly in the same place on every activity and i have bout 20 activities at the moment but will rise a lot higher soon, and i don't really want to be copying and pasting the same code in to each activity, so I'm looking for a simple, efficient solution to handle the onClick event which will work globally throughout the app.

For example, if User A clicks on the sign in button on Activity 1 and signs in, it will show that he is signed in on Activity 2 and 3 and so on.. until they log out.

The sign in button has the same ID throughout the whole application which is "@+id/signIn"

Would it be easier to call a single function at the beginning of each activity? I thought that wouldn't be every effective use of processing power etc?!

Any suggestions and/or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, why does your app need 20 activities with the exact same button?

Comment: Because there is a title bar at the top of each activity which has the logo and the users name etc

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use the same Activity and replace the the title bar (or replace the logo and username) for each one onCreate()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't avoid implementing that listener in all of your activities in either ways. But you can do it in a bit more organized way:

You could write a custom header layout for your application (`/res/layout/header.xml`), in which you have the "Sign In" button with a click listener set (pointing to an `onSignInClicked` method):

```
android:onClick="onSignInClicked"
```

Then you include this header to each activity layout:

```
<include android:id="@+id/header" layout="@layout/header" />
```

You could also create an interface which contains an `onSignInClicked` method declaration, and by all your activities implementing that interface you force them to define the `onSignInClicked` method's body.

What you actually do there can also be wrapped into

- a static method inside a globally
  accessible class, or
- a well-parametrized method inside
  your `Application` extension class.

so in all of your activities this method can be:

```
public static void onSignInClicked(View view)
{
    // static method with call with reference to the current activity
    SignInHelper.doSignIn(this);
}
```

or

```
public static void onSignInClicked(View view)
{
    // global method in your `Application` extension
    // with reference to the current activity
    ((MyApplication)getApplicationContext()).doSignIn(this);
}
```

If you choose the second way, don't forget to update your `androidManifes.xml` by setting the `name` attribute of your `application` tag:

```
<application android:name=".MyApplication" [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the button as a [custom view.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)