# How to create custom home button which shows for all activities of my project?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

[image]

How to create picture type of home button which shows for all activities of my project.
i have 4 or 5 activities is there.

I want to click that button go back to main window. please give me code

first how to create a home button

Comment: [Multiple activity same button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848964/same-button-on-multiple-activities) This above link has discussion about what you want this may help you!!!
Welcome

Comment: "please give me code?" how many times do we have to mention that SO is not a site where you get people to code for yor free ?

Comment: please give me a code ,first how to create a that type of home button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) and a dashboard might be better suited to what your trying to do, or just use an options menu. Have a look at ['Google I/O 2010 - Android UI design patterns'](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0) on youtube. That will help you ask clearer questions. Motodev Studio will help getting started with what you learn in the video (but I personally don't like the code generated).

If after watching the video above you still want the home button like your screenshot you could probably use a relative layout with a layout include or fragment aligned to the bottom, with the include or fragment containing a image button.

Actually both methods above require similar code, but action bars are *cool*.